# rails infinate scrolling loads 2 times single page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi i am trying to create a infinite scrolling in rails with pagination gem. no other specific gem i am using for this.it works fine with loading a content but i loads a single page means next page 2 times instead of one time. even the request to the server goes from the page only once response also only once but content is coming 2 times.

i have tried to look how it returning the content 2 times but unable to find how it's working. some one can help me ??

**JS to send a request for a 2nd page while Scrolling the page**

```
$(window).on 'scroll', ->
    more_posts_url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
    if more_posts_url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 60
      $('.pagination').html('<p>Loading......</p>')
      $.ajax more_posts_url,
      type: 'get'
      dataType: 'script'
    return
```

**the controller where the request will received**

```
 def show
@follow_unfollow = FollowerDetail.new
@songs = Song.user_filter(@user.id).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
respond_to do |format|
    format.html { }
    format.js { }
end
```

end

**the response JS from this controller**

```
$('#my_songs').append("<%= j render partial: 'songshow' , :collection => @songs %>");
<% if @songs.next_page %>
   $('#infinite-scrolling').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @songs %>');
<% else %>
   $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have been stuck with something like this, but I used [this](https://github.com/bodrovis/SitePoint-InfiniteScroll) repo. It contains a nice piece of code for infinite scroll. It's written with CoffeeScript though, bu shouldn't be too difficult to convert it to a JS.